# RightFax 9.3 Available Disk Space?

Tags: fax

We are currently running RightFax 9.3 as our fax server. I was just in the RightFax Enterprise Fax Manager resolving another problem and noticed 2 little red exclamation marks in the lower left hand pane. I have one beside "Available disk space for fax images" and one beside "Available disk space for fax database". Both are labeled with 5%? What is this? How can this be resolved? I have plenty of physical storage left on the server drives so I am curious as to which space it is referring to??

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the "Available disk space for fax database" if your RightFax server is running FP2 SR4 and above.  I would highly recommend that you make sure you are on the latest code level for RightFax 9.3, which is 9.3 FP2 SR6.  The "Available disk space for fax images" is very important, because this counter can stop your RightFax server from processing jobs.  The counter is a percentage of disk space, so you could still have 10+GB of free disk space on the drive that RightFax is installed on, but if that is only 3% of your total disk space RightFax will see that as a problem, and will stop processing jobs.

Free up disk space on the drive that RightFax is installed on, and there are options to move some of the RightFax folders to different drives that will also help.